# php coding style comparison vs return

Tags: php, if-statement, coding-style, return

there is two ways or more i can make that function 
one why is using more returns and return every time i do not need continue with the function and another way is using
more ifs,else ifs, elses,

```
function getCountOfWhatEverMethodType1
{
    $return = false;
    // ----
    if($user->isLogged)
    {
        if(getDBOBlaBla->equal(1))
        {
            $return = 2;
        }
        else if(getDBOBlaBla->equal(2))
        {
            $return = 3;
        }
        else
        {
            $return = 1;
        }
    }
    // ----
    return $return;
}

function getCountOfWhatEverMethodType2
{
    if(!$user->isLogged)
    {
        return false;
    }
    $return = 1;
    // ----
    if(getDBOBlaBla->equal(1))
    {
        $return = 2;
    }
    else if(getDBOBlaBla->equal(2))
    {
        $return = 3;
    }
    // ----
    return $return;
}
```

with one i should use and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return something, usually the better option is to return something when the condition is met.

I would do it this way:

```
function getCountOfWhatEverMethodType3()
{
    if(!$user->isLogged)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // ----

    if(getDBOBlaBla->equal(1))
    {
        return  2;
    }
    if(getDBOBlaBla->equal(2))
    {
        return 3;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

For me this style is better for 2 reasons:

1. You can remove some if/else statments so you can code faster and there's less code in case you need to modify or analyze that
2. You don't create temporary variables because you don't need them.

In fact each person has it's own coding preferences in such statements and if all work you can use any of them. But even look at your previous code - you made some mistakes (used null that was unnecessary) and using the above version it would be harder to do such mistake

Comment: hey thanks i updated the code i made some error before

Comment: i see but still i can't understand why is is better (if it) using Type3 inside of 2 or 1

Comment: @user3301396 explanation added